# freetype 2.7 возвращение старого режима хинтинга для шрифтов TrueType

Tags: linux, шрифты, opensuse

Во `freetype` в версии `2.6.4`, а после и в `2.7` появился новый режим хинтинга, который используется по умолчанию.
Как вернуть старый режим хинтинга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В директории системных профилей `/etc/profile.d` создаём, если не создан, и открываем, файл `freetype2.sh` и раскомментируем или прописываем строку

```
export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"
```

При перезагрузке иксов или всей системы можно снова наслаждаться приятными и чёткими шрифтами.